# converting & to &amp; for XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am building a XML RSS for my page. And running into this error:

```
error on line 39 at column 46: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
```

Apparently this is because I cant have & in XML... Which I do in my last field row...

What is the best way to clean all my `$row['field']'s` in PHP so that &'s turn into `&amp;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode just the HTML special characters `&`, `<`, `>`, `"` and optionally `'` (see second parameter `$quote_style`).

Answer (score 2):

It's called [htmlentities()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [html_entity_decode()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: XML does not share all of the same *named* entities as HTML - having only 5 predefined entities (amp, lt, gt, quot, and apos). Unless the XML document has a DTD attached to it that includes all of the HTML named entities, using htmlentities(), which converts could convert some characters into entities that an XML parser is not required to support.

Comment: @ian: Given Gumbo's description of `htmlspecialcharacters()`, I would go with that (as it only touches the 5 characters with predefined entities in XML)

Answer (score 2):

Really should look in the dom xml functions in php. Its a bit of work to figure out, but you avoid problems like this.

Comment: How so? Point me to something and I will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Convert Reserved XML characters to Entities

```
 function xml_convert($str, $protect_all = FALSE)
{
    $temp = '__TEMP_AMPERSANDS__';

    // Replace entities to temporary markers so that
    // ampersands won't get messed up
    $str = preg_replace("/&#(\d+);/", "$temp\\1;", $str);

    if ($protect_all === TRUE)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/&(\w+);/",  "$temp\\1;", $str);
    }

    $str = str_replace(array("&","<",">","\"", "'", "-"),
                        array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;", "&#45;"),
                        $str);

    // Decode the temp markers back to entities
    $str = preg_replace("/$temp(\d+);/","&#\\1;",$str);

    if ($protect_all === TRUE)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/$temp(\w+);/","&\\1;", $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
html_entity_decode($row['field']);
```

This will take and revert back to the & from & also if you have &npsb; it will change that to a space.

http://us.php.net/html_entity_decode

Cheers

Comment: Not sure why I would want to revert... This is for a RSS feed.